Windows 11 network connection error. I think something with ssl/tls
I came across with the network problem on Windows Home 23H2. One day, my Outlook 2010 has break to receive letters. In the log, I got the message error 0x8004210A.
I tried all the methods pointed here, here, and in other places
I've checked internet connection, server's ports 995 POP & 465 SMTP with telnet, etc - all works fine. But mails have'nt receive.
Later, I've taken attention - when I've tried to reinstall Office - I can't activate it. Tried to install Kaspersky - installator can't download components. But Internet works, I can go to any site, can download via http, ftp etc.
I think something happened with ssl/tls libraries, but don't know what certainly is it and how to settle it.
Please help

Hi John, thank you for the hint. But updating doesn't work too. Any service which required ssl/tsl- can't connect to servers. Maybe I'll download the whole package

@John, I'll admit at first reading I thought this question was .Net related myself, but its not actually. Office2010 did not make much use of .net framework components.  Op, the SSL/TLS implementation used by office is part of the OS, and Win11 will have the latest/greatest protocol and version support. It is possible that outlook 2010 requires retired protocols like TLS1.0/1.1 but I would get confirmation that that is your problem before you try to muck around with the SChannel protocol support in the registry

@FrankThomas, all was working nice till 3 April, then suddenly I got "The operation timed out waiting for a response from the receiving (POP) server 0x8004210a." After attempt to reinstall Office, I've seen I can't to activate it, can't install nothing via web-downloaders, can't to update via WSUS, but I connected to Internet and can download all stuff via browser

@FrankThomas, I've compared registry settings \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL with fine working machine - it has the same settings
